# JQUERY - $.get(url,data,function(data),'html') not working on IE

Tags: jquery

JQUERY 1.5

```
function loadPostQry(str) { 
    $.get( 'fillpage.php','prodcode='+str, function(data) { 
        $('#s_content').html(data); 
    },
    "html" ); 
}

this piece of code is running on every browser but not on IE. I think there's something missing, the XHR or something else that has got to do with the engine.
```

//Dont get confused with this one, The above code is what I'm trying to get some answers...

JQUERY 1.4

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest;
    }
    else {
        try {
            return new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        }
        catch(ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to accomplished like the ver1.4 code...

Q: How would I write that piece of code to be compatible to ver1.5, everytime that code is called it will first check the engine.

This is an exerpt from JQUERY site...

> --xhr--- Default: ActiveXObject when available (IE), the XMLHttpRequest
>   otherwise Callback for creating the
>   XMLHttpRequest object. Defaults to the
>   ActiveXObject when available (IE), the
>   XMLHttpRequest otherwise. Override to
>   provide your own implementation for
>   XMLHttpRequest or enhancements to the
>   factory

Need a work around.. Thanks...

Comment: What happens when it doesn't run? Any errors?

Comment: You got two different snippets, but I can't actually see how they are related, and why the one is 1.5 and the other is 1.4.

Comment: @Pekka, no error but it does not return any data from an external page.

Comment: Not certain it will make a difference, try formatting the data parameter as { procode: str }. Check the URL that jQuery is creating. Is it what you expect?

Comment: @rob but you are sure the request is actually executed?

Comment: @GolezTrol, the 1.4 code is an XmlHttpRequest which i been using long before the jquery 1.5 version. It checks the browser whether it is IE or not and return the corresponding XHR for non-IE and ActiveXObject for IE. The thing is how would I make this code to the one above.. I think that is the problem. Got any idea?

Comment: @rcravens - that code is ok for some browser, but not on IE, i have tried that {prodcode:str} but nothing happens..

Comment: @Pekka, yes indeed... The problem is on IE browser itself, not on the other... Do you have any idea on how to check XHR and ActiveXObject on jquery1.5?

Comment: @rob so the request fires, but doesn't return any data? You're 100% positive? This might be an 1.5 bug but I would be really surprised. And I still don't understand what you do with the XHR object in the second block. Were you using jQuery before 1.5?

Comment: Anyway, checking for XHR and ActiveXObject is exactly the thing that jQuery was designed to make unnecessary. There *must* be a better way around this.

Comment: @Pekka - yes I am 100% positive. No, the second block is not the problem, I am trying to compare it on how to use that code to 1.5 coz I'm confused with the JQUERY XHR on 1.5 since on the documentation "Default: ActiveXObject when available (IE), the XMLHttpRequest otherwise", do I get the docs wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I too am having a difficult time understanding your question, but I think you are asking how to access the native XHR object in the same way you did in versions previous to 1.5.  If your question is how to check whether the browser supports XMLHTTPRequest, you shouldn't have to do that; that's the whole point of using jQuery.

The ajax method in jQuery 1.5 returns a jqXHR object, which is an augmented version of the native browser XHR object that was returned in earlier versions.  This object is a superset of the native browser XHR object, so all methods and properties of the original are inherited.  If you want access to the jqXHR object, the following code will work.  I have created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/parkerault/YmdQJ/, and can confirm that it works in IE7 and IE8.

```
var loadPostQry = function(str) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/fillpage.php',
        cache: false,
        data: {
            prodcode: str
        }
    });
};

var complete = function(jqXHR, status) {
    document.write('returned: ' + jqXHR.responseText + '\nwith status: ' + status);
};

var jqxhr = loadPostQry('pancake');
    jqxhr.complete(complete);
```

Any properties that you were able to access from the browser XHR object before 1.5 will still be accessible from jqxhr.

Comment: the code is working on other browser, but i don't know how it did work on IE.